# My app working in iphone 5 but not in 3 why?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have made an application in Xcode 4.5.1 with Mountain Lion as OS. Now my problem is, it is working in the iPhone 5 but not in iPhone 3, how to fix this issue?. if it works, in both case the height differs, it is a native application which is opened in the web view???

Comment: How can anyone answer this question when you haven't even explained what the problem is (e.g. what happens when you try to run your application). You haven't explained what you have done already, and you haven't told as at least what your application does or whether both iPhones are running the same OS.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: If keep deployment target to 5.0 the app is running good ...
when i changed to 4.2 it is showing an error like clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires iOS 5.0 or later)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1....@dreamlax  @ Ashley Mills @ Rohan Kapur

Comment: @DineshTeja can you check your deployment target in your project info.

Comment: Try using Xcode 4.5, 4.2 is so old school

Comment: @Rushi  I changed in both deployment target in targets and projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the new version of Xcode, the default setting of i386 Architectures includes the new iphone 5 armv7s. Some of the items we were linking in, did not include armv7s and we were bugging out. Needed to change the Workspace (in our case) not to be the default arch, but to specify armv7 only.

Edit:

1. In Xcode navigate to Build Settings and find Architectures group (it’s on the top, so hard to miss). Add armv6 to Architectures line. It should contain armv6, armv7 or Standard (armv6 armv7)
2. Set Base SDK to Latest iOS (currently set to iOS …)
3. Uncheck Build Active Architecture Only or set it to NO.
4. Valid Architectures must show armv6 armv7 When your project uses
   your own dependent libraries, build them with the same (correct)
   configuration.

Comment: I didn't get you will u please tell what have to change

Comment: I will check and tell thank you